# Android Bluetooth Event Receive Data

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am developing an android application and I have a little difficulty to develop program.
When I receive file by bluetooth, I need send this file by email automatically.
my application does not start until it has received the file, ie the transfer by bluetooth makes the operating system ...

I've been testing FileObserver class but there is a problem, when I receive the file then used a method to send email, but while running that method is passing the file via bluetooth, is there any way to make it wait until the file is sent completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("mailto:" + "your_email"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your_subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your_text");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: yeah, but i cant launch this intent if not put an event on receive the file

Comment: @user2210642: you want to know how to add the file as an attachment?

Comment: I want to know how to launch the intent when i receive the file,

Comment: check this link http://manojprasaddevelopers.blogspot.in/2012/02/bluetooth-data-transfer-example.html

Comment: i receive data from android bluetooth (it runs android),  I want that when i receive the file 'just in this moment'  send them by mail

Comment: While transferring file use AsyncTask in that you can use postExecute()

Comment: when i receive the file completed , i send by email, the problem is that when finish the transfer an event should send the file by email.

Comment: yes I understood.. Did you find out in which line your file was sent

Comment: If you connect your bluetooth,sincronice, and you receive the file, not need create code.

Comment: yes While transferring file use AsyncTask in that you can use postExecute()

Comment: but when i transfer the file? remember that i do not use code to transfer the file by bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

In order to add file as an attachment use:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, <ure to file>);
```

For example: `Uri.fromFile(file);`

Comment: Please update/clarify your post to something readable. It is totally not clear what your problem is.